# Constraints/auto-layout with two textboxes side by side

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to place two textboxes side by side to eachother and keep their relative width/position when I rotate the device or change devices. I'm trying to understand constrainst and auto/layout but it seems slightly confusing. I can get it to work with one textbox but not two..

Here's what I currently have.
[image]
This is the device in portrait mode. The two textboxes are constrained 20 to the left and right with equal gap of 26 in between of them leaving their width to be 174.

[image]

Then when I rotate the device to landscape mode, I get this..
[image]

The textbox on the right is now much larger than the textbox on the left and the constraints on the right one seems to have changed

[image]

While the constraints on the left textbox now appear to be empty..
[image]

What I would like is to have the two textboxes keep the gap in between them relative so when I rotate the device either their width scales to match the gap or even if their width doesn't scale then increase the gap between them to match the width..
Something like this
[image]

Constraints are too confusing :cry:

Edit:
Attempt with horizontal stackview
[image]

But the textboxes are really small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of auto-layout, a simple solution would be

1) Take a Horizontal stackview, give constraint to top, left, and bottom, give a height of 44, or something else

2) give spacing of the stackview which you want , like 10

3) then add two textfields to the stackview

4) Set the distribution of stackview fill equally.

Comment: So is this not possible with an auto-layout? I'll try your advice and let you know if it works.

Comment: When I try to embed in a horizontal stack view the textboxe widths become really small and I can't change it..

Comment: added both textfields? added the fill equally distribution?

Comment: Yes both text fields are in the stackview with an equal fill distribution. I posted an image of what it looks like.

Comment: You have skipped the first step. give top left and right padding of the stackview, add a height as your wish. I see the textfields inside the stackview are equally distributed

Comment: Oooh! That makes sense. I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to do is to also add the width of the first and second element to always be equal.

programmatically it can be done like so.

in VFL it would be something like this:

```swift
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[firstElement]-20-[secondElement(==firstElement)]|", // sets the horizontal space
                                                        options: [], 
                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                        views: ["firstElement": textBox1, "secondElement: textBox2]) // sets the reference of the horizontal space
)
```

The constraints will be guaranteed that both element will be of the same width with a 20 px distance between them.

Using `NSLayoutConstraints`

```swift
textbox1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true // sets the textbox 1 and leading of the super view
textbox2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textbox1.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true // sets the textbox2 and textbox 1 gap
textbox2.trailing.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true // sets the textbox 2 and the trailing of the super view
textbox1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textbox2.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true // sets the textbox1 to be of same width as textbox 2
```

IB outlets TBH are a bit a headache. I tend to do most of my UI's via code, but it can also be done in xib's i'm just not well-versed in xib's anymore.

Comment: Ah. THank you for the feedback ! I imanaged to do it with horizontal stackview but yes I don't know why Apple made xibs such a pain to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Since you got it to work with `UIStackView`, I will focus on the `autoLayout` part. What you have to know is that all `autoLayout` needs is enough constraints to know an element's width, height, x and y.

From the image you posted, I can see that the right constraint of your left `UITextField` is to the right end of the screen and not to the `UITextField` on the right. So that is one thing that needs to change. I don't see any other constraint related problem so I'm gonna start from the beginning.

Left `UITextField`:

- Add a left constraint and top constraint (let us say 15 each)
- Add a right constraint to the right UITextField (again 15)

Right `UITextField`:

- Add a right constraint and top constraint (again 15 each)

Now these constraints are not enough and here is why

Both the `UITextFields` have the vertical hugging priority so Xcode doesn't know which textfield to expand when things get cluttered. Lowering one of the values will fix the problem and always keep the width of one textfield same while expanding the other. Basically the `UITextFields` cannot figure out their widths.

Possible solutions:

- If you want the `UITextField` to change its width: Like i said above, change the vertical hugging priority of one textfield if you want it to expand
- If you want both `UITextField` to be same width with constant spacing (Like in the image): Apart from the above constraints just add an equal width constraint to both the UITextField

[image]

And voila (using the second solution):

[image]

Also,
If you want the widths to remain the same and gap between them to expand. Instead of equal widths set the constraint to a fixed width and instead of having a 15 fixed spacing between the `UITextFields`, change it to be `>= 15`.

Comment: "If you want both UITextField to be same width with constant spacing (Like in the image): Apart from the above constraints just add an equal width constraint to both the UITextField" I took your advice and I did try this but how do I add an equal width constraint? Also thank you I much prefer this solution.

Comment: Press control and drag from one `UITextField` to another. And a black menu thingy will show up that will have that option.